# How to add Secure URL for Custom rewrite URL In Magento custom Module

Tags: magento-1.8

Am trying to add secure URL to my custom module - below is my config.xml sample code

```
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <scheme>/scheme/</scheme>
    </secure_url>
    <routers>
        <scheme>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Companyname_Scheme</module>
                <frontName>scheme</frontName>
            </args>
        </scheme>
    </routers> 
</frontend>
<global>
    <rewrite>            
        <myschemes>
            <from><![CDATA[/myschemes\/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[scheme/user/$1/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </myschemes>
    </rewrite>
```

My need is to make myschemes url to access only through https://  if the user forced to load on non http i.e., http:// .

If i add secure url for myschemes then above rewrite is not working. If i enter https://www.example.com/myschemes/ as url it is redirecting to https://www.example.com/scheme/user//

How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Interesting question, I was curious how this worked myself so I did a little digging. If you take a look at the standard router (`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard`) you'll see that it makes a determination if a route should be secure by using `_checkShouldBeSecure`, which will in turn call `_shouldBeSecure` and this will ultimately call `Mage_Core_Model_Config::shouldUrlBeSecure`.

From here you can see that the way to force a URL to be secure is to declare the path so in your modules XML code. To take an example from core, which you can see in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml`.

```
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <customer>/customer/</customer>
    </secure_url>
</frontend>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about rewrites, but this is how you force secure urls on your own controller actions.

```
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <namespace_module_controller_action>
            /frontname/controller/action
        </namespace_module_controller_action>
    </secure_url>
</frontend>
```